# Can you make a method that changes different variables depending on a string input

Tags: javascript

im trying to create a method that can update the value of different variables. here, "a" would be a string containing the name of the variable that i want to change the value of.

`varupdate(a,b) {`

`this.a += b;`
`}`

Comment: be clear about your need ..be more descriptive

Comment: You can simply assign a new value without the need for a method.